# Why can't I take this gym down?

Tags: pokemon-go

Level 10 Valor gym. I'm Mystic. Gym has 10 Gastly CP 46-48. I attack. I take no damage. Prestige goes from 50k to 48k. When I go in for another attack, prestige is back at 50k? I can't take down this gym.

Comment: Is the low-CP Gastly still the first Pokémon you face or is it something else?

Comment: If it only went down 2k, did you run from the gym after beating 2 of the Gastly?  My gut is saying either a bug, or hax.

Comment: it's possible someone else in the area was training in the gym at that time. it could also be bugged

Answer (score 2):

It is being trained up again.
Since there are really bad Pokémon in there the gym owning team can train it back up really fast as well as you can take it down really fast. Also they have the advantage that you need a lot more time to take out a Pokémon (and eventually give up trying).

To counter those guys you'll need more manpower in order to do more damage than they put back in or another time to attack when they're not around to camp the gym.

Also, if they're cheating (using bots) you can't do much about it other than trying to overpower them with a few guys attacking at the same time. Or they'll eventually get banned. A good way to identify botters is looking for their names. If they're all similar they're bots.